# Align FontAwesome icon to <h1>

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, icons, alignment, html-heading

I'm quite new to learning Bootstrap, but I have some trouble aligning my icon on the same line as my .

[What it looks like right now..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnf37.png)
I've been trying to fix it within the container, but also with rows, columns and several aligning methods.
This is my code right now:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
    <h1 class="mb-3 ml-5">Products</h1>
    <button class="filterIcon navbar-toggler float-right align-self-start" type="button">
        <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
      </button>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong? I can't really seem to find the answer in documentation as well. If someone does have documentation, please show me so I can learn from it :).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a flex layout to get the items aligned side by side and in the center vertically. For bootstrap, this means using the classes  `d-flex` and `align-items-center`

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha256-+N4/V/SbAFiW1MPBCXnfnP9QSN3+Keu+NlB+0ev/YKQ=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col d-flex align-items-center">
      <h1 class="m-0" style="flex-grow:1;">Products</h1>
      <button class="filterIcon navbar-toggler" type="button">
        <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```